# Use Socket in Application as a global object

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android project written in java and I want to use the same socket in all the activities without shutting it down and turning it up back again.
One method I've found is putExtra but I found another method to create the socket in MyApplication file, and to reach it everytime you need it from that file but I didn't understand this method.
Can someone please help me understand it or maybe found some explanation online and can send it to me because I couldn't find anything.

Don't know where to start after I've created the MyApplication file which extends Application.

Comment: Make a singleton